# 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, function

when I enter

```
guest_list = [('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]

for guests in guest_list:          #guests is a tuple
    
     res = "{} is {} years old and works as {}.".format(guests[0], guests[1], guests[2])
     print(res)
```

it works fine
But when I change it to

```
def guest_list(guests):

    for guests in guest_list:

        res = "{} is {} years old and works as {}.".format(guests[0], guests[1], guests[2])
        print(res)
guest_list([('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]
```

I get

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,

KidBlue

Comment: As suggested by the error message, check what type `guest_list` is now. Hint: consider renaming your function (and also the input it takes)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over function name guest_list instead of list name guests.
The code inside the guest_list function should be as follows

```
for item in guests:
   #print item
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
def guest_list(guests):
```

to:

```
def show_guest_list(guest_list):
```

The function name was conflicting with `guest_list`.  And the argument needs to be `guest_list` rather than `guests`.

Then invoke it as:

```
show_guest_list([('Ken', 30, "Chef"), ("Pat", 35, 'Lawyer'), ('Amanda', 25, "Engineer")]
```